# Locally link url()s in CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, background-image

I am trying to get a background image for my web page. I have a link to an external style sheet, which works fine (the CSS applies), but when I try to get the background image using `background-image` it doesn't show the result. I have tried both absolute and relative URLs

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
        <meta name="created" content="Wed, 26 Mar 2014 04:01:34 GMT">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <title>Welcome to CSS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="welcome.css" />
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image:url('C:\Users\Neo\Documents\CoffeeCup Software\My
Website\Files\images.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Please check for your backward slashes...This should be something likebackground-image:url('Users/Neo/Documents/CoffeeCup Software/My
Website/Files/images.jpg');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set `absolute path` from your locally. you can set absolute path only live web page. following way,

```
 BODY { background-image: url(http://www.bg.com/pinkish.gif) }
```

another way set `relative path`. I assume your root Website folder

```
 __My Website
      |__Files
          |__images.jpg
      |__welcome.css
      |__welcome.html
```

It's relative to the style sheet, but I'd recommend making the urls relative to your url, base on above strutted set relative path on following way,

```
 background-image:url('Files/images.jpg');
```

Comment: beginner time this kind problem face. but Stackoverflow always say to you welcome questioner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background-image:url('Files/images.jpg');
```

Comment: @user3447875 You said you tried it and it didn't work, and now you accept another answer that is identical to my earlier answer. Am I missing something?